# C# Linq Query to get highest status from the table given

Tags: c#, linq

This is my model in which Chart, ChartStatus and Coder are virtual objects

```
public class ChartHistory : ModelBase  
{  
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
    public long Id { get; set; }  
    public virtual User Coder { get; set; }  
    public virtual ChartStatus ChartStatus { get; set; }  
    public virtual Chart Chart { get; set; }  
}
```

In the table I have values like this

```
    CoderId  ChartStatusId  ChartId  
    1           9            2  
    3           10           2  
    1           9            45  
    3           10           45  
    3           9            43  
    4           10           43   
    6           9            41  
    7           9            40
```

I want to get all the chartIds but with highest `chartStatusId` 
The result should be

```
    CoderId  ChartStatusId  ChartId   
    3           10           2   
    3           10           45  
    4           10           43    
    6           9            41  
    7           9            40
```

Can someone help me with creating a linq C# query for this.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Can you post what code you do have that you are having problems with?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: ChartId and ChartStatusId are they in an sql table?

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = from item in Ent.tableName 
                group item by item.Id into g 
                select new {
                                      Id= g.key,
                                      status= (from t in g select      item.status).max()
                                  };
```

Comment: public class ChartHistory : ModelBase
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual User Coder { get; set; }
        public virtual ChartStatus ChartStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual Chart Chart { get; set; }     in the above where I am setting g.key as Chart.id I am unable to do it.....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` to group the items by `ChartId`, and then select the `Max` value of `chartStatusId` for each group using `System.Linq`.

This example uses the following simple class:

```
public class Chart
{
    public int ChartId { get; set; }
    public int chartStatusId { get; set; }
}
```

And then uses `GroupBy` and `Max` to get a new list of items for each `ChartId` that contains the `Max` value of `chartStatusId`:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var charts = new List<Chart>
    {
        new Chart {ChartId = 1, chartStatusId = 1},
        new Chart {ChartId = 2, chartStatusId = 1},
        new Chart {ChartId = 3, chartStatusId = 1},
        new Chart {ChartId = 1, chartStatusId = 2},
        new Chart {ChartId = 2, chartStatusId = 2},
        new Chart {ChartId = 3, chartStatusId = 2},
    };

    Console.WriteLine("ChartId  chartStatusId");

    var filtered = charts
        .GroupBy(c => c.ChartId)
        .Select(c => new Chart {ChartId = c.Key, chartStatusId = c.Max(i => i.chartStatusId)});

    foreach (var chart in filtered)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{chart.ChartId,4}{chart.chartStatusId,11}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: public class ChartHistory : ModelBase
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public virtual User Coder { get; set; }
        public virtual ChartStatus ChartStatus { get; set; }
        public virtual Chart Chart { get; set; }     in the above where I am setting g.key as Chart.id I am unable to do it.....

Comment: *"I am unable to do it"* doesn't tell me much. What error do you get?

Comment: Please show the code you're using based on the answers given so we can see where it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed SQL Database Structure:**

Entity Framework Requires a Primary Key to function correctly if you do go this route.

[Sql Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkDSk.png)

**Code Using EntityFramework Against SQL Table:**

```
  using (var db = new TestEntities())
        {
            var dbCollection = db.Charts.ToList();
            var chartCollection = dbCollection.ToLookup(x => x.ChartID);
            foreach(var chart in chartCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{chart.Key} | {chartCollection[chart.Key].Max(x => x.ChartStatusID)}");
            }

        }
```

**Result:**

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0rgA.png)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you add only virtual objects to link your Entities?
So the first step must be to add the property of CoderId, ChartStatusId, ChartId if you want LINQ query.

```
public class ChartHistory : ModelBase  
{  
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]  
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Coder")]
    public int CoderId { get; set; }  

    [ForeignKey("ChartStatus")]
    public int ChartStatusId { get; set; }  

    [ForeignKey("Chart")]
    public int ChartId { get; set; }  

    public virtual User Coder { get; set; }  
    public virtual ChartStatus ChartStatus { get; set; }  
    public virtual Chart Chart { get; set; }  
}
```

Then add migration and update DB. If all names and types are equal current DB state (or snapshot in case EF Core) the migration shoud be empty.
Now, you have access to Id properties of linked entities, so the query will be:

(I suppose that your DbSet field in context named ChartHistories)

```
 _db.ChartHistories.GroupBy(p => p.ChartId)
    .Select(p => new{ p.CharId, p.ChartStatusId })
    .ToList()
```

If you can't modify class and add fields for any reason your only way to use Raw SQL queries:

If you use [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql)

If you use [EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)